# How to avoid loading CSS file for ipad sized devices ('between' mobile and full-sized)?

Tags: html, css

I have an application that has a good look on screens, but has a rigid framework that makes difficult to use it in mobiles and similar.. So I've made an specific CSS file to fit these devices. That's ok, I use a *main.css* that defines general looking (for all media) and a *handheld.css* file that makes corrections for this kind of devices:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="handheld,tv" type="text/css" href="handheld.css" />
```

The problem is that some devices like an iPad have a great looking with the general screen version and don't need to downgrade like in some mobiles. So I have put in my app a link that sets a cookie that forces to display like in a desktop screen. The problem is I don't know how to force to not load *handheld.css*. Javascript may be? But, how?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is media queries. This won't solve your question, but it is how you should go about solving the bigger problem (layout responding to different screen sizes) in the future. **Example**: http://www.barackobama.com/ (resize the width of page to see what it does) **Learn how**: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/ http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/media-queries/ http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/introducing-media-queries.html http://designmodo.com/media-queries/

Comment: Just a comment. Typically when I go to a site on a mobile device it will detect that and redirect me to another version of the site designed for mobile usage. I then have the option to view the full version if I would like to. To me it seems like this is a great option, however it requires you to keep nearly two identical versions of the same site.

Comment: google "load css based on screen size".  Here is one of the hits that seems reasonable: http://www.warriorforum.com/website-design/10031-script-load-different-css-depending-screen-resolution.html

Comment: @Danny: I hate it when websites do that. What do they think? We are still on WiMo 6 with IE? :-)

Comment: This looks like a package that solves your issue: http://responsejs.com/

Comment: @PeeHaa It's useful when your phone has a 320x240 resolution like mine.

Comment: @JamWaffles: now I feel bad for you :( :P

Comment: @PeeHaa I feel bad for me. I'd buy a better phone in a jiffy, but I'm _poor_, so I _can't_ \*tantrum ensues\*.

Comment: @CoryDanielson this is great, thanks, but don't resolves my problem: I need to give users a button/link to change from "mobile mode" to "desktop mode".

Comment: I posted an answer for you, it seems to work fine in ie, ff and chrome. Haven't tested it on a mobile device though.

Comment: I've got the solution working on jsfiddle, and tested it with ie, ff, chrome and an android phone... works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is **media queries**. This won't solve your question, but it is how you should go about solving the bigger problem (layout responding to different screen sizes) in the future. 
**Example**: http://www.barackobama.com/ (resize the width of page to see what it does)
 
**Learn how**:
 
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/
http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/media-queries/
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/introducing-media-queries.html
http://designmodo.com/media-queries/

To solve your specific problem, read below:
**working example of website with css stylesheet switching**: 
http://jsfiddle.net/y6FWK/2/

This is something new to me... Wasn't expecting it to work so easily, but, since the `<link>` is just another dom element, you can just refer to it (easiest to give it an id) and simply change it's `href` value... I was surprised.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" id="cssSwitch" />
```

Then some buttons to change the css... or whatever you'd like

```
<input type="button" id="enableMobile" value="mobile css" />
<input type="button" id="enableMain" value="main.css" />
```

Then, within your code:

```
$("#enableMobile").on("click", function(){
    $("#cssSwitch").attr("href", "handheld.css");
});

$("#enableMain").on("click", function(){
    $("#cssSwitch").attr("href", "main.css");
});
```

To my surprise, it [actually worked](http://jsfiddle.net/y6FWK/2/).

**Tested and worked in**

- IE (8)
- Chrome (15)
- FireFox
- Android Samsung Galaxy S (default browser)

Answer (score 4):

How about using mediaqueries?

- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

You can use them to target devices with width less then 800px for example. It will work on most modern mobile browsers.

To make css apply only to mobile version, I personally prefer creating namespaces to adding/deleting css-files.

For example:

1. You write all rules in the handheld.css as ".handheld .classname".
2. For mobile version you add class ".handheld" on body.

It is also useful to create non-js versions of the pages: You have class ".nojs" on body by default, and on load removing it by Javascript (if it is enabled).

Comment: Yes, that's true, but it don't resolves the problem. The problem is how to force, not how to detect. Imagine a user that has a device that allows only a 640x400 screen, but he thinks that is better to use my website doing scroll than to see a bored text only screen. I have to provide a option to see it :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Didn't understand it from question (thought that the problem is that iPad have resolution 1024, so it would work good with desktop grid, but responds to mobile rules in css media). Easiest way to do that you want is by adding class to body for handheld version and write all handheld classes as ".handheld .classname", or so I think.

Comment: Edited answer to add info about switching.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the `User-Agent` header server-side and then determine whether you should serve handheld.css or not. Depending on what your server-side language/framework is in there are numerous libraries that can help you determine the user's device/os/etc. Keeping in mind, of course, that `User-Agent` can be spoofed. But it should be good enough for most visitors.

Comment: Eh, user agent sniffing is probably not the best way to solve the issue.

Comment: Agreed - it is generally accepted that user-agent sniffing isn't really a practical method for dealing with browser variation any more, you need to work in terms of capability detection.