# iPad as not specific view

Tags: c#, ipad, mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

Based in this post http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features that shows how identify an specific view.

The MVC4 indentifies the request by iPad as an Mobile, but i would like that it recognize as Desktop instead Mobile, so i used the following code:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("")
{
    ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf("iPad", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
});
```

Is there another better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle multiple screen resolutions across multiple devices would be through the Cascading Stylesheet.  You can actually dictate which resolution should run variations of your layout.

You can also culminate it with Javascript, which can allow you to create a truly Dynamic Resolution Dependent Layout.  An example of such can be found [here](http://www.particletree.com/features/dynamic-resolution-dependent-layouts/).

You can do a `Media Query` for your stylesheet, or a `Viewport`.

An example would be:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

    #pagewrap {
        width: 95%;
    }

    #content {
        width: 60%;
        padding: 3% 4%;
    }

    #sidebar {
        width: 30%;
    }
    #sidebar .widget {
        padding: 8% 7%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

That will take any screen smaller then 980px and adjust the page.

You can find several adjustments here about [such as well](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries). That article you mention is actually suggesting the use of `Media Queries` and `Viewports` as well.

An important note, several mobile devices have increased the resolution.  So it may appear they look and handle a normal desktop site correctly but they often don't.  For instance, a `hover effect` does not work correctly on a phone as they single-tap.  It doesn't know when the hand is above the button.  So often touchscreens don't handle desktop interfaces correctly.  Keep that in mind during your design.

Hopefully that helps, or points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks very much Greg, i am using the stylesheets to identify the screens sizes, my layout is already responsive, but now, i need develop a version for mobiles and i wish that ipad will be not identified as mobile.

Comment: I understand, what I'm saying is you'll have to identify the resolution of the iPad and use that as a focal point so it is no longer considered "mobile".  The above example does address your concern in how to do it; some additional detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233788/how-to-avoid-loading-css-file-for-ipad-sized-devices-between-mobile-and-full